# Excel Formula to Calculate Text within a date range

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate values within a specific date range. The data I want to split between each month and the values: Successful, Incomplete and Failed.

I've tried pivot tables with this data but it doesn't work for me, also lacking pivot table excel experience. Formulas I'm more comfortable with.

I am using the following statement to at least get the total number of a value I add into it;

```
=COUNTIF('Jan 19'!$C$2:$C$1159,"Value")
```

Example If I put into the value "Successful" I get the total number of successful records.

I am looking into having a formula that I can input a specific month/date range (Jan, Feb, etc) and a value to get a count.

```
Ex. =Formula ((RangeOfData, "Value") AND (RangeOfData, (FromDate, 
ToDate))
```

I expect to the get the total number of a value(s) within a specific date range. If there isn't any data then the results would be blank or zero.

Comment: You may want to look into [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-DDA3DC6E-F74E-4AEE-88BC-AA8C2A866842)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the formula COUNTIFS() as @cybernetic.nomad pointed in the comments so you can put more conditions on the COUNT:

```
=+COUNTIFS('Jan 19'!$B$2:$B$1159,">="&F3,'Jan 19'!$B$2:$B$1159,"<"&G3,'Jan 19'!$C$2:$C$1159,H3)
```

In the formula above I guessed the dates are in the COLUMN B, if not, you need to change it in the formula above.

To do that we should put the range we want to look at in a couple of cells where you would put the date range, in the example above:

- F3 is the start date (if you want February of this year should be 1/2/2019).
- G3 is the final date (if you want February of this year should be 1/3/2019).
- H3 is where you can write "value", "successful" or any other string you are trying to count.

Comment: I ended up finding success with the following;

Comment: =COUNTIFS(Source2019!$C$2:$C$4535,"Successful",Source2019!$V$2:$V$4535,">="&DATE(2019,5,1),Source2019!$V$2:$V$4535,"<="&DATE(2019,5,31))